# Powershell - How can I get my PSCustomObject to show two outputs

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```
$DISKPhysical = Get-PhysicalDisk
$DiskErrors = Get-Disk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter

    $DiskResults = [PSCustomObject]@{
    
        'Device ID' = $DISKPhysical.DeviceID
        'Model' = $DISKPhysical.Model
        'Serial Number' = $DISKPhysical.SerialNumber
        'Connector Type' = $DISKPhysical.BusType
        'Disk Type' = $DISKPhysical.MediaType
        'Health Status' = $DISKPhysical.HealthStatus
        'Size' = '{0:n0} GB' -f ($DISKPhysical.size/1GB)
        'PowerOnHours' = $DiskErrors.PowerOnHours
        'Read Errors' = $DiskErrors.ReadErrorsUncorrected
        'Wear' = $DiskErrors.Wear
        'Temperature' = $DiskErrors.Temperature
    }

$DiskResults | ConvertTo-JSON
```

This currently returns the information if there is only 1 'Physical Disk'.

```
{
    "Device ID":  "0",
    "Model":  "Micron_1100_MTFDDAK256TBN",
    "Serial Number":  "18301DD5EF41",
    "Connector Type":  "SATA",
    "Disk Type":  "SSD",
    "Health Status":  "Healthy",
    "Size":  "238 GB",
    "PowerOnHours":  895,
    "Read Errors":  0,
    "Wear":  0,
    "Temperature":  26
}
```

However when I have 2 or more Physical Disks like a USB Stick, I get the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.
At line:4 char:5
+     $DiskResults = [PSCustomObject]@{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I know this is because the PSCustomObject only returns the first value, how do I get it to return multiple devices like this:

```
{
    "Device ID":  "0",
    "Model":  "Micron_1100_MTFDDAK256TBN",
    "Serial Number":  "123456789",
    "Connector Type":  "SATA",
    "Disk Type":  "SSD",
    "Health Status":  "Healthy",
    "Size":  "238 GB",
    "PowerOnHours":  895,
    "Read Errors":  0,
    "Wear":  0,
    "Temperature":  26
},
{
    "Device ID":  "1",
    "Model":  "Cruzer Edge",
    "Serial Number":  "123456789",
    "Connector Type":  "USB",
    "Disk Type":  "Unspecified",
    "Health Status":  "Healthy",
    "Size":  "30 GB",
    "PowerOnHours":  null,
    "Read Errors":  null,
    "Wear":  0,
    "Temperature":  0
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Kyle

Comment: just to be painfully obvious ... your problem is caused by stuffing _multiple_ disk objects into _one_ PSCO. [*grin*] the solutions below work by iterating thru the info and building _one_ PSCO for _each disk_ instead of trying to shove _two-or-more disks_ into _one_ PSCO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe the output from `Get-PhysicalDisk` to `ForEach-Object`:

```
$DiskResults = Get-PhysicalDisk |ForEach-Object {
    # Fetch operational details only for this disk
    $DiskErrors = Get-Disk -UniqueId $_.UniqueId | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Device ID' = $_.DeviceID
        'Model' = $_.Model
        'Serial Number' = $_.SerialNumber
        'Connector Type' = $_.BusType
        'Disk Type' = $_.MediaType
        'Health Status' = $_.HealthStatus
        'Size' = '{0:n0} GB' -f ($_.size/1GB)
        'PowerOnHours' = $DiskErrors.PowerOnHours
        'Read Errors' = $DiskErrors.ReadErrorsUncorrected
        'Wear' = $DiskErrors.Wear
        'Temperature' = $DiskErrors.Temperature
    }
}

$DiskResults | ConvertTo-JSON
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, just changed the 'UniqueId' to 'DeviceID' and getting a perfect result.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use foreach.

I would suggest something like this bellow (not a tested, you may need to adjust !!!)

```
$DISKPhysicals = Get-PhysicalDisk
$DiskResults += foreach ($DISKPhysical in $DISKPhysicals )
{
$DiskErrors = Get-Disk -FriendlyName $DISKPhysical.FriendlyName  | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter

        [PSCustomObject]@{
   
        'Device ID' = $DISKPhysical.DeviceID
        'Model' = $DISKPhysical.Model
        'Serial Number' = $DISKPhysical.SerialNumber
        'Connector Type' = $DISKPhysical.BusType
        'Disk Type' = $DISKPhysical.MediaType
        'Health Status' = $DISKPhysical.HealthStatus
        'Size' = '{0:n0} GB' -f ($DISKPhysical.size/1GB)
        'PowerOnHours' = $DiskErrors.PowerOnHours
        'Read Errors' = $DiskErrors.ReadErrorsUncorrected
        'Wear' = $DiskErrors.Wear
        'Temperature' = $DiskErrors.Temperature
    }
}

$DiskResults | ConvertTo-JSON
```

Comment: Thank you! With this code I get duplicate answers: 
{ DeviceID : 0 
........
DeviceID : 1
.........
DeviceID : 0 
........
DeviceID : 1
.........
}